# Rails 4 and search with Sunspot: is it possible to prevent n+1 queries when retrieving search results?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, sunspot

Take this code for example

```
   @results = @search.results.nil? ? nil : @search.results.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

I am using the bullet gem, and because this is searching my "Posts" model and each "Post" has a link to the user, I am getting an n+1 query warning. I have tried

```
  @results = @search.results.nil? ? nil : @search.results.includes(:user).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

But I get

```
   undefined method `includes' for <   <Sunspot::Search::PaginatedCollection:0x007f7f5cae5578>
```

Is there a way to more efficiently do this?

Comment: Could you provide the code of your results method?

Answer (score 4):

That's it:

```
Post.search(include: [:user])
```